# プログラムでICCIDを取得する方法

Tags: ios, objective-c

プログラムでICCIDを取得する方法を教えていただきたいです。
本家で同様の記事を見つけたのですが、出力はnullになってしまいます。

本家の方法
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599471/iphone-ipad-unique-identifier-besides-uuid-udid
NSString *commcenter = @"/private/var/wireless/Library/Preferences/com.apple.commcenter.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:commcenter];
NSString *ICCID = [dict valueForKey:@"ICCID"];

Comment: その投稿は4年前のものなのでいまのiOSでは動かないんじゃないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

現在のiOSではICCIDなどのユニークな識別IDを取得することはできません。

本家の方法として貼られているリンクの中で行っているように、
ユニークなIDを自作するしかないかもしれません。

参考までに下記ページでもICCIDの取得ができないと書かれていました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314439/how-to-get-the-iccid-of-the-sim-card-that-is-in-the-iphone-using-my-ios-app